# Where are application files stored?

Tags: filesystem, filemanager

I have installed few software in Ubuntu. Some of these software are quite big and needs more than 400MB of space during installation. In Windows, when we install a software, it is saved in program files, where we can see all the files.

What is the path of the equivalent location for Ubuntu? I mean, in which path, I can see that, there is a folder for that particular application and entering that, I can see all 400MB+ data.

Comment: i didn't find the exact answer, what i wanted. as i don't have much reputation, so, i couldn't comment either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linux programs are commonly using shared libraries, so the program install size is dependant of what libraries it would need. So there is not a way to see all installed stuff in one directory. But you can query files that are owned by package with:

```
dpkg -L <package_name>
```

for example you installed samba, you could query it's files by:

```
dpkg -L samba
```

Hope that helps? Here is the explanation for filesystem places of different items:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxFilesystemTreeOverview